# Picturebox tabindex in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am using .net framework 2.0 version, in my login form i have a picture box for sign-in. I need to give tab for this picture box. please guide me in this.

Comment: give tab for picture box ? .. what is that for ?

Comment: yes , when i click tab key picture box should be selected.

Comment: picturebox have no tabindex property .. if it could, what would you do after it selected ?

Comment: I want to control the form by keyboard keys. if it's selected pressing enter key should do the on mouse click event functionality.

Comment: I think you cant do that since the picturebox is unfocusable control ..

Comment: on surfing in net I found that it has the property of tab index but i cannot set this in my code.

Comment: It seems like you want the picture box to be a button. Why don't you just use a button instead? You could have a picture on the button.

Comment: Yes now i have changed it to a button,when i click TAB key the button got selected but when i click ENTER key nothing happen. I have write code on button1_keypress.Private Sub Button1_Keypress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Button1.KeyPress
        If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 13 Then
            MsgBox("do something here")
        End If
    End Sub this is not working when i click enter key. please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to use a click-able Picture on your form, 
I would suggest you use a `Button`, and add an `Image` on the button.
The Image property is accessible from your list of properties. Then, you can manipulate it as a simple button, that is the `Button_Click()` event.